# How to add Domain using ArcGIS Diagramer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-diagrammer

Is it possible to add domain to XML Schema of GDB using ArcGIS Diagramer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. I am using [ArcGIS Diagrammer for 10.2](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=51b6066bfd024962999f6903682d8978) but 10.1 should work fine, too.

1. Add a new domain (both types work fine). Add coded values or define the range. Then choose File > Publish. Save an .XML document.
2. Now right-click your geodatabase in ArcGIS Desktop application of your choice and choose Import > XML Workspace Document. Browse to the saved .XML document and the domain you have specified in the Diagrammer will be appended to the existing domains (if there were any already defined).

[image]